# Cells as array Excel

Tags: arrays, excel

I want to use list of cells as range

what i want to do is to use specific cells into `Trimmean()` function like this:

```
=trimmean([B1, B9, B11, B3], 25%)
```

I found out that `{1;2;3;4;5}` works just like array but not with reference cells

I would prefer not using VBA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

`=TRIMMEAN(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},B1,B9,B11,B3),25%)`

where the upper value in the array constant:

`{1,2,3,4}`

should be equal to the number of cells being considered (in this case 4).

If that number is quite large, then, so as not to have to construct by hand the required array constant, you can use the following version, which requires committing as an **array formula****

`=TRIMMEAN(CHOOSE(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,AREAS((B1,B9,B11,B3)))),B1,B9,B11,B3),25%)`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*